# Running Jest from node in a CRA application with expose-gc

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

I'm having **issues with memory leaks** coming from running my test suites with Jest where memory usage keeps growing with each suite.

After searching through the net, I've found that this could be related to a **garbage-collector behaviour**, and multiple Github threads suggest running this command:

`node --expose-gc ./node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js --coverage --runInBand --logHeapUsage`

The issue is that **my project uses React (with CRA not ejected) and Typescript**, so whenever I run this script it throws a `Syntax error` because of Typescript.

I've tried installing `ts-jest` library but it does not work. It may be related, but running the `ts-jest` *setup init* complains about already having a configuration due to CRA.

I've been searching and I have not found anything, since all related threads are about the known memory leaks Jest has, but none explain how to execute the `node` command with the `expose-gc` in a project with React and Typescript.

- Is there any way I can expose the GC to the Jest script used by CRA so I can keep using the same configuration as until now?
- Otherwise, how can I execute the `node --expose-gc jest` parsing my files so that it does not throw an error?
- I'd also need to use the `--inspect-brk` to see where the leak comes from, so even if the `--detect-leaks` works, I still need to find a way to execute my Jest config from `node` command.

Thank you!

Comment: I've found the `--detect-leaks` option, which needs the `weak-napi` package installed. It seems it actually exposes the garbage collector to the Jest execution, and it fails any test in which detects memory leaks. If your tests do not have any memory leaks, this should work to expose and use the GC (actually, tests that had 1GB memory usage now are running under 200MB with this setting). I'm going to do some further tests to be sure.

Comment: The `--detect-leaks` option works, but it doesn't tell me where the leaks are. I need the `--inspect-brk`, and that needs, too, the `node` command, so I've got the same problem I had initially.

Comment: I've found that running react-scripts in the command seems to do the trick, but it does not accept any Jest parameters and I don't know if that's because it's not the right module or the right way `node --inspect-brk node_modules/react-scripts/bin/react-scripts.js --env=jsdom --runInBand`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reviewing [the documentation from Jest](https://jestjs.io/docs/troubleshooting#debugging-in-vs-code), I've seen this section which suggests to run the debug configuration in VS Code calling `react-scripts`. After playing a little bit with it, **this is the command that got it working:**

`node --inspect-brk node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/test.js --no-cache --env=jsdom --runInBand`

As you can see, **you have to call the `test.js` file inside `react-scripts` directly**, and then you can send all the arguments you want to Jest, as you'd normally do when running tests directly from the terminal of your project.

If you execute this script:

`node --inspect-brk node_modules/react-scripts/bin/react-scripts.js test --no-cache --env=jsdom --runInBand`

You will be able to attach to the node debugger, but you won't be able to set `debugger` stops in your test files, as it will attach to the main process, which is `react-scripts` (and not the `test` script itself).

Hope this might help someone in a future!